# Why the extra text in my XSLT output?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is an example of the XML and XSLT:

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <count>5</count>
  <idx>10</idx>
  <cds>
    <cd>
      <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
      <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>CBS Records</company>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
  </cds>
</catalog>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/catalog/cds">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="cd">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Question**: Why is it that when transforming the given XML document the content of the elements **`count`** and **`idx`** is being printed out before the table all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XSLT *built-in templates* (documentation for [XSLT2](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) and [XSLT3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule)) are doing that. Specifically:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

You can override, or simply change your template from matching `cds`

```
<xsl:template match="/catalog/cds">
```

to matching `/`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

and the spurious text node output will be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Using a "base" XSL file in my actual project made things a bit more complicated, but all is good now.

Answer (score 3):

The only template that you have written matches `<xsl:template match="/catalog/cds">`, processing however starts at the document node, in your case with a built-in template https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule, so you will have to write a template matching `/` or `/catalog` or you will have to make sure you write templates that don't output anything for the elements you don't want to produce any output.

Comment: Thanks Martin. It worked. Using a "base" XSL file in my actual project made things a bit more complicated, but all is good now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to override the built-in template rule in your stylesheet with a version that does nothing:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="#all"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the link in my answer to the moved page on XSLT built-in templates!